# How to control the amplification of a Transistor?

Tags: transistors, guitar-pedal

I'm currently building a very simple overdrive/distortion pedal using a 2N5089 transistor.

I want to be able to have a potentiometer control the "drive" which I assume is the voltage amplification. Do I do this by changing the base current?

Hopefully this isn't a stupid question and I appreciate all responses and any guidance in learning more and more about electronics in this area.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE where schematics are the language we all speak. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar. If you're using an existing design then paste in an image of the schematic and a link to the text.

Comment: @PatricoFerris as has been said, a good place to start learning is by looking at similar circuits on the internet. The website listed below has schematic diagrams of lots of well known guitar effects pedals. Start by trying to understand how they work.  You could even build one or two. Then figure out how to modify them. Then you may be able to design one yourself.  http://www.generalguitargadgets.com/how-to-build-it/technical-help/schematics/

Comment: A simple google search of tagged "guitar pedal" in the question yields results like "[Simply put, overdrive strives to emulate the interaction of a guitar plugged into a tube amp.](https://articles.boss.info/whats-the-difference-between-overdrive-and-distortion/)" and "[while an overdrive pedal pushes your signal pretty darned hard, it doesn't change your existing tone much](https://www.sweetwater.com/insync/boost-overdrive-distortion-fuzz-pedals-whats-the-difference/)"

Comment: Another clue to what the question is asking for is in the title "How to control the amplification of a Transistor?". For [2N5089](https://www.theengineeringknowledge.com/introduction-to-2n5089-npn-amplifier-transistor/), amplification is controlled by setting the [gain of the transistor](https://microcontrollerslab.com/2n5089-npn-transistor-pinout-examples-features-applications-datasheet/) with the circuit resistors. See https://microcontrollerslab.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/2N5089-transistor-as-an-amplifier.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to get variable gain, like a volume control is to put a potentiometer in front of a fixed-gain amplifier.  Set the amplifier to the maximum gain you ever want, then use the pot to scale down the input signal you feed into the amp.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I appreciate all of the help people give.

Comment: I'd put the potentiometer on the output of the fixed-gain amplifier in order to reduce noise contribution to the input signal.

Comment: @Harry: That's not usually good.  Lould signals will then clip the amp, even though they would have been attenuated by the volume control later.  For a single-stage amp, just put the volume control before it.  For a multi-stage amp, you can put the volume control on a intermediate signal that isn't as sensitive to noise.  But, you still have to make sure that intermediate signal will not clip with the maximum valid input.